# How to fix error: Cannot register 2 metrics with the same name: /tensorflow/api/keras/optimizers

Tags: tensorflow, keras, python-3.9

When I am trying to run a Python code for deep learning utilizing the TensorFlow library, I am getting the following error:

```
2021-10-24 10:07:13.619481: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found
2021-10-24 10:07:13.619752: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
2021-10-24 10:07:18.797570: E tensorflow/core/lib/monitoring/collection_registry.cc:77] `Cannot register 2 metrics with the same name: /tensorflow/api/keras/optimizers`
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\Compressed\Face-Mask-Detection-master\detect_mask_image.py", line 5, in <module>
    from tensorflow.keras.applications.mobilenet_v2 import preprocess_input
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\api\_v2\keras\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from keras import __version__
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from keras import models
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\models.py", line 20, in <module>
    from keras import metrics as metrics_module
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\metrics.py", line 26, in <module>
    from keras import activations
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\activations.py", line 20, in <module>
    from keras.layers import advanced_activations
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from keras.engine.input_layer import Input
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\input_layer.py", line 21, in <module>
    from keras.engine import base_layer
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 43, in <module>
    from keras.mixed_precision import loss_scale_optimizer
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\mixed_precision\loss_scale_optimizer.py", line 18, in <module>
    from keras import optimizers
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\optimizers.py", line 26, in <module>
    from keras.optimizer_v2 import adadelta as adadelta_v2
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\optimizer_v2\adadelta.py", line 22, in <module>
    from keras.optimizer_v2 import optimizer_v2
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\optimizer_v2\optimizer_v2.py", line 36, in <module>
    keras_optimizers_gauge = tf.__internal__.monitoring.BoolGauge(
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\monitoring.py", line 360, in __init__
    super(BoolGauge, self).__init__('BoolGauge', _bool_gauge_methods,
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\monitoring.py", line 135, in __init__
    self._metric = self._metric_methods[self._label_length].create(*args)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.
AlreadyExistsError: Another metric with the same name already exists.
```

Environment:

Python version: 3.9

OS: Windows

Library: TensorFlow API

Comment: Make sure you did not install tf-nightly and tf at the same time in the same environment.

Comment: If my answer helped you, please remember to mark it as the best answer, you're welcome :)

Answer (score 10):

This appears to be a bug with tensorflow 2.6 see https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/unable-to-import-keras-models-on-tensorflow-2-6-0-jetpack-v46/191904

I had the same issue and solved it by downgrading to tensorflow 2.5 until the issue is resolved in a future update.

**Edit: 2.7 is out and seems to have fixed the issue.

*Note: I am using tensorflow with my CPU, not a GPU.

Answer (score 8):

Update: TensorFlow has now released version `2.7.0` ([here](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/2.7.0/)), so using the latest version will fix your issue.
This specific bug was fixed in version [2.6.2](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases/tag/v2.6.2) though actually.

---

I starting having this issue yesterday during a Github CI build job, but the code was running locally fine.

I solved it by temporarily downgrading to TensorFlow 2.5.2 until the issue is resolved in a future update.

Version 2.5.2 is the latest version before version 2.6.0. I confirmed 2.6.0 and 2.6.1 didn't work for me (at the time of writing).

Answer (score 3):

I happen to have encountered about the same problem on a CI build job today, and wasn't occurring yesterday. So I investigated, and the culprit seems to be keras 2.7 and not tensorflow: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/15585

On my end, the solution was to constraint the version index of Keras to <2.7 but I'll report back if a more stable fix is implemented.

Cheers!

EDIT: the patch release of TF 2.6.2 fixes this (the formerly loose version constraint for keras). So either add a constraint <2.7.0 for keras with your existing TF version or upgrade to TF 2.6.2!

Answer (score 1):

Here, you have got two issues:

1. CUDA installation missing.
2. TensorFlow library issue.

For the first case, you can follow the procedure described [here](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/1433/how-to-fix-tensorflow-warning-could-not-load-dynamic-library-cudart64-110dll-dlerror-cudart64-110dll-not-found)

For the issue with the TensorFlow, what worked for me is to downgrade Keras to 2.6.0 using `pip install keras==2.6.0` (it should be probably 2.6.1 as of now) to same version as TensorFlow (in my case, TensorFlow version is 2.6.0). Please let me know it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Encountered this while running code on external GPU, resolved it by upgrading TensorFlow to the 2.7 version