# SolverProblemError on install Tensorfow with poetry

Tags: python, tensorflow, python-poetry

when i add tensoflow with poetry (poetry add tensorflow) i get this error :

```
Using version ^2.7.0 for tensorflow

Updating dependencies
Resolving dependencies... (0.8s)

  SolverProblemError

  The current project's Python requirement (>=3.6,<4.0) is not compatible with some of the required packages Python requirement:
    - tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem requires Python >=3.6, <3.10, so it will not be satisfied for Python >=3.10,<4.0
    - tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem requires Python >=3.6, <3.10, so it will not be satisfied for Python >=3.10,<4.0
    - tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem requires Python >=3.6, <3.10, so it will not be satisfied for Python >=3.10,<4.0

....

    For tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem, a possible solution would be to set the `python` property to ">=3.6,<3.10"
    For tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem, a possible solution would be to set the `python` property to ">=3.6,<3.10"
    For tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem, a possible solution would be to set the `python` property to ">=3.6,<3.10"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error message tells you, that your project aims to be compatible for python >=3.6,<4.0 (You probably have `^3.6` in your pyproject.toml), but pytorch says it's compatible only for >=3.6, <3.10. This is only a subset of the range of you project definition.

Poetry doesn't care about your current environment. It cares about a valid project definition at all.

The solution is already suggested within the error message. Set the version range for python in your `pyproject.toml` to `>=3.6, <3.10`.

Comment: But what if other deps require >=3.8 <= 3.12? Than it wont work

Comment: For me the solution was hardfixing my python version to 3.10.12; not ideal but got the install

Answer (score 2):

There is a conflict between the Python and the Tensorflow version in your project. As the message suggests, you can set the Python version between `3.6` and `3.10`. I can confirm `python=3.8` works well with `tensorflow=2.7.0` today in Ubuntu 20.04. This new Tensorflow version has been released last month, and it fixes the recent `AlreadyExists` [error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69694944/how-to-fix-error-cannot-register-2-metrics-with-the-same-name-tensorflow-api) that happens with Tensorflow and Keras in the other versions, so I can recommend using this combination.

Answer (score -1):

I would love to comment this, but my reputation...

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = ">=3.8, <=3.10.6"
tensorflow = "^2.11.0"
...
aw-client = "^0.5.11"
```

You can choose a specific subset that is smaller than both your project's and other libraries.

As stated, your poetry project aims to be compatible for python 3.6<=python<4.0, but pytorch says it's compatible only for >=3.6, <3.10, a subset of your project's goals. My python version is 3.10.6 - aw-client requires above 3.8 - tensorflow requires 3.6 to 3.10, so choose a subset that works.

Run `poetry check` to see if everything is set up properly at the end!

:)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33899046)

Comment: I did exactly this - doesn't work