# How to add tensorflow dependency to poetry project without limiting the range of supported python versions?

Tags: python, tensorflow, python-poetry

I have a **package** built with poetry. The package requires `tensorflow` (most recent version to date is 2.12.0). To be able to run `poetry add tensorflow` I need to change the supported python version to `python = ">=3.8,<3.12"` as suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70356867/solverproblemerror-on-install-tensorfow-with-poetry). However, if I then try to add my package to a freshly initalized poetry project (with python version 3.8) I receive an error. I would like to have a rather user-friendly package, where a simple `poetry add <package>` will not fail.

#### Steps to reproduce

I have a package with `python = "^3.8"`.Trying to add `tensorflow` to my package, getting the following error:

```
...
For tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem, a possible solution would be to set the `python` property to ">=3.8,<3.12"
...
```

Following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70356867/solverproblemerror-on-install-tensorfow-with-poetry), I change the python version to `python = ">=3.8,<3.12"`. Then I am able to add `tensorflow`

```bash
poetry add tensorflow
```

I initalize a new project with poetry (with default values and no dependencies) with python3.8.

```bash
poetry init
```

When trying to add my package

```bash
poetry add <package>
```

I receive following error

```
The current project's Python requirement (>=3.8,<4.0) is not compatible with some of the required packages Python requirement:
  - <package> requires Python >=3.8,<3.12, so it will not be satisfied for Python >=3.12,<4.0

Because <project> depends on <package> <version> which requires Python >=3.8,<3.12, version solving failed.

  • Check your dependencies Python requirement: The Python requirement can be specified via the `python` or `markers` properties
    
    For <package>, a possible solution would be to set the `python` property to ">=3.8,<3.12"
```

I would like to have add my package to the freshly initialized project without any errors. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Hi, was this ever resolved? I am encountering the same issue.